# Finding Column Average

Tags: 2013, jquery, custom-list, calculated-column

Created a custom list in SharePoint 2013.  I have a column that is full of numbers.  I would like to find the average per column.  To solve this issue I created a calculated column and applied this formula (see below) But it's not working.  Is it possible to add the numbers in a column to find the average similar to excel?

```
 =AVERAGE([Column1])
```

Comment: You want the average at the bottom of a column, or multiple columns in one row averaged together?

Comment: @ErinL Sorry for not being clear in my question.  If possible, I would like the average at the bottom of the column.  Thanks for your help

Comment: The second option in my post below gives instructions for that. The average will be at the top of the view.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To average multiple columns in an item, you'd use a calculated column such as `=AVERAGE([Column1],[Column2],[Column3])`.

To average a column, edit the view and expand the Totals section. By your column name, if it's a number, you can select average (etc) from the dropdown.

Comment: I am assuming if you are trying to average from a column that has a formula (calculated column) attached the 'Total' option will not work, correct?

Comment: That's correct.